# Pass by reference in templated class

Tags: c++, templates

Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template<class T>
class Number {
private:
 T val;
public:
 Number(T& tRefArg) : val(tRefArg) {}
 void print() {
  std::cout << val << std::endl;
 }
};

template<class R>
class RoundedNumber : public Number<R> {
public:
 R val;
public:
 RoundedNumber(R& tRefArg): Number<R>(tRefArg), val(tRefArg) {
  val = floor(val + 0.5f);
 }
 void print() {
  std::cout << val << std::endl;
 }
};

int main() {
 int i = 8;
 Number<double>* myNumber = new RoundedNumber<double>(i);
}
```

Gives error:

> 2.cpp:30:56: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘double&’ from an rvalue of type ‘double’
>     Number* myNumber = new RoundedNumber(i);

I assume it is treated as rvalue but why?

Comment: Why would you pass by reference? Btw, you have two `val`s in `RoundedNumber`.

Comment: Ah, don't know why i didn't noiced conversion :) Thanks!

Comment: @user3655463 put the comment in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member functions expect a `double`, you are providing an `int`. A temporary `double` is created from the `int` and you cannot bind a temporary to a reference, but you can bind it to a const reference.
That is, you can use this:

```
Number(const T& tRefArg) : val(tRefArg) {}
```

Or this:

```
Number(T tRefArg) : val(tRefArg) {}
```

And this:

```
RoundedNumber(const R& tRefArg): Number<R>(tRefArg), val(tRefArg) {
```

Or this:

```
RoundedNumber(R tRefArg): Number<R>(tRefArg), val(tRefArg) {
```

Comment: Additionally rvalue reference can be used: RoundedNumber(R&& tRefArg): Number<R>(std::move(tRefArg)), val(tRefArg)